# Why is Guice throwing $ComputationException from UncaughtExceptionHandler in main?

Tags: java, guice

I'm trying to run an application that uses Guice and starts a Netty HTTP server. This is using Java 8.

However, at startup I see this error in the console:

```
Exception: com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"
```

No stack trace, nothing else.

What would be causing this error?

Comment: Which Guice version are you using?

Comment: This is with Guice 3.0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Guice 3.0 is incompatible with Java 8 (see this [issue](https://github.com/google/guice/issues/757)). You must update to at least [4.0](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Guice40#some-highlights).